# Why some parts of the object don't move with the armature?

Tags: rigging, armature, weight-painting

I tried to fix the bones so that things could look better but these things keep staying in place. And when I subtract weight paint on some parts it becomes bumpy.

[image]

[image][image]

Answer (score 1):

The first reference picture looks like some vertices have no vertex groups (weightpaint) assigned.

You can fix it by selecting the responsible vertex group in the Properties Tab -> Object Data Properties (the green triangle icon), switch to Weightpaint Mode and use some blur brush on those lacking parts.

This helped me a lot so far.